# Counting number of words start with UpperCase letter in strings, java

Tags: java, loops, io

I have tried to write a Java program that count number of words start with UpperCase in each line separately, like in a txt file, and **print the line number next to the number of words start with UpperCase in that line.**

I have only come out with how to count the number for a single line using:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = new String();
System.out.println("Enter a line:");
s = " " + in .nextLine();
char ch;
int count = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
    ch = s.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isUpperCase(ch) && (i == 0 || Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i - 1)))) {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println("total  number of words start with capital letters are :" + count);
```

I tried to do it on the way I want, but it keep showing me "File is empty":

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("io-02.txt");
Scanner inScanner = new Scanner(in);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("io-02-out.txt");
PrintWriter pwr = new PrintWriter(out);

int linenumb=0;
String s="";
char c;
int count = 0;
inScanner.useDelimiter("");

for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
    s = " " + inScanner.nextLine().trim();
    c = s.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isUpperCase(c) && (i == 0 || Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i - 1)))) {
        count++;
    } else if(s == "\n"){
        if(linenumb == 0)
            pwr.printf("%6s%35s%n", "Line#", "Number of Uppercase characters");

        linenumb++;
        pwr.printf("%5d.%35d%n", linenumb, count);
        count = 0;
    }
}

if(linenumb == 0)
    System.out.println("Error: The input file is empty");
else{
    linenumb++;
    pwr.printf("%5d.%35d%n", linenumb, count);
    System.out.println("The file output.txt has been created . . . ");
}
```

Please help.

Comment: What stops you from doing the same thing for multiple lines? Do you have a problem with loops, with reading from a file? Overall understanding of the problem? Other reasons?

Comment: I have a problem with reading from a file. I have tried to do it, but it's not working probably because I didn't understand IO very well.

Comment: Ok, but then you should show us the code that makes problems (where you read from the file), and state your problem. What is not working, and why you think it should be working. We will not write the program for you, but help you fix issues. Therefore, please edit your question so we chan take a look at the actual problem.

Comment: the code is added now.

Comment: You need to move this line to before your loop:   s = " " + inScanner.nextLine().trim();. This reads the file, so you are looping on your initialise value (String s = "")

Comment: Still showing the same message.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 solution:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;




final public class UppercaseWordCounter { // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49193228/counting-number-of-words-start-with-uppercase-letter-in-strings-java


    final private static File FILE_WORDS = new File("io-02.txt");
    final private static File FILE_RESULTS = new File("io-02-out.txt");


    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        if (!FILE_WORDS.exists()) {
            System.err.println("Input file does not exist: " + FILE_WORDS);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        if (FILE_RESULTS.exists()) {
            if (!FILE_RESULTS.delete()) {
                System.err.println("Intended output file exists already and can't be deleted: " + FILE_RESULTS);
                System.exit(2);
            }
        }

        try (final BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(FILE_WORDS.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
             final BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(FILE_RESULTS.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {

            int lineCounter = 1;
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                final int upperCaseWordsInThisLine = countUpperCaseWords(line);
                bw.write("Line " + lineCounter + " has " + upperCaseWordsInThisLine + " upper case word" + (upperCaseWordsInThisLine == 1 ? "" : "s") + ".\n");
                lineCounter++;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }


    private static int countUpperCaseWords(final String line) {

        int ret = 0;

        final int length = line.length();
        boolean newWord = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            final char c = line.charAt(i);
            if (" .,;/".indexOf(c) >= 0) {
                newWord = true;
            } else if (newWord) {
                newWord = false;
                if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                    ret++;
                }
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a method from Files class, which is available from java 1.7

```
List<String> lst = Files.readAllLines(Path path, Charset cs)
```

then you can loop over the `lst` List checking your condition

Comment: I'm a beginner and haven't reached this level, that's why I tried to do it in this way. :(

Comment: It's better to loop over the file with myBufferedReader.readLine() because that saves you memory. A reader can easily be created these days (Java 8.) with java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(). While memory realistically is no problem here (I assume), as a learning experience it would be better.